# Adding Custom JavaScript into Individual Weebly product pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, customization, html, weebly

I am trying to add an Age verification code to only certain categories on my Weebly store but can't figure out how to implement it on only certain pages. I tried adding an "Embedded element" to the pages but the script doesn't run. the code I am trying to get to work is:

```
'<script    type="text/javascript"  src="https://custom.ageverify.co/shopshag/av.js"></script>'
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://custom.ageverify.co/shopshag/av.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to accomplish this is with the site http://age-verify.com. They provide the code snippet and there is a free plan.

Comment: that is what i am using but it only works on the entire when I put it in the footer section of the SEO settings and I only need it for certain categories.

Comment: Try adding it to the category template file. If you only want it to run on certain categories, you will have to make a custom category template. [Custom Weebly Theme](http://christopher.su/2014/create-custom-weebly-theme/)